# Can't import java.lang.reflect in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, reflection, dependency-management

I'm trying to import java.lang.reflect in a java file of a maven project, but I get "error cannot find symbol" on the import line. It can't find java.lang either. This is a built in Java lib, right? I didn't think I needed to add any dependencies for a default java lib. Is there a certain dependency I need to define to gain access to this lib?

Comment: Can you paste your pom.xml file also?

Comment: Can your IDE identify JRE?

Comment: I suggest getting your code to compile in an IDE first, and then trying to build it with maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you importing a fully classfied class name or just the package?

The folowing is a valid statement:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
```

While import java.lang.reflect would try to find a class 'reflect' in package java.lang resulting in "cannot find symbol"